# Implement STL functions in variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have been working on a small project to get up to speed with variadic templates. I implemented a small multidimensional array. I would now like to define a function that operates on the nearest neighbours of a given position -- is there an elegant way to retrieve the values of the neighbours of a given position in my array?

```
template<class T, size_t size, size_t... sizes>
struct MArr {
    typedef std::array<typename MArr<T, sizes...>::type, size> type;

    std::array<MArr<T, sizes...>,size> data;

    MArr<T, sizes...>& operator[](int i) {
        return data[i];
    }

};

template<class T, size_t size>
struct MArr<T, size> {
    typedef std::array<T, size> type;
    type data;

    T& operator[](int i) {
       return data[i];
    }

};
```

Addendum: It is somewhat clear to me how to loop all elements by employing recursion, e.g. applying an arbitrary function to a hyperdim. array of ints:

```
template <typename T, size_t size>
void func(MArr<T, size>& arr, std::function<void(int &)> f) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       f(arr[i]);
    }
}


template <typename T, size_t size0, size_t size1, size_t ...sizes>
void func(MArr<T, size0, size1, sizes...>& arr, std::function<void(int &)> f) {
    for (int i =0; i < size0; i++) {
        func<T, size1, sizes...>(arr[i], f);
    }
}
```

I am curious how I would generate something like `func(arr[i+1,j,k,…],arr[i-1,j,k,…],arr[i,j+1,k,…],arr[i,j-1,k,…],…)` and a given func (which, say adds the respective elements). As I said, quite new to variadic templates and I have the feeling I don't have the right mindset yet …

Comment: Are those direct neighbours only or diagonal ones too? i.e., does a 2D cell have 4 or 8 of them?

Comment: The direct neighbours -- so in 1D -> 2, 2D -> 4, 3D -> 6 …

Comment: Looks to me like `func` is basically suitable. All you need to do is remove the loop, adjust the indexes a bit and add a flag if you already moved 1 step.

Comment: Your mindset seems to be pretty on-point. There are minor issues such as using `typedef` instead of `using` and unnecessarily copying an `std::function`, but you got the gist of it. Might be worth posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ once it does what you want.

Comment: @nwp, thanks for your comment. I am unsure how to go about defining the particular function because of the variable length of indices. Could you expand a little bit more? Basically I want to be able to select a certain element and then call a function on all of its neighbours … I think it would be fairly easy if I had a fixed number of indices, but in this particular case I seem to be a bit lost …

Comment: Something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8ee5bcabe98da00) is what I was thinking. You can default `stepped` to `false` by creating a wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

You may do something like (code use folding expression from C++17, but can be written in C++11):

```
template <std::size_t I, typename F, std::size_t ... Is, typename Tuple>
void helper(F&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>, const Tuple& t)
{
    f((std::get<Is>(t) - (Is == I))...);
    f((std::get<Is>(t) + (Is == I))...);
}

template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is, typename Tuple>
void helper(F&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...> Seq, const Tuple& t)
{
    (helper<Is>(std::forward<F>(f), Seq, t), ...);
}

template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
void apply_to_neighboor(F&& f, Ts... indexes)
{
    helper(std::forward<F>(f), std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>(), std::tie(indexes...));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/833dd4ecee49569f)

If you want to retrieve all neighbours, you might change above code to:

```
template <std::size_t I, std::size_t ... Is, typename Tuple>
auto helper1(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const Tuple& t)
{
    return std::make_pair(std::make_tuple((std::get<Is>(t) - (Is == I))...),
                          std::make_tuple((std::get<Is>(t) + (Is == I))...));
}

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename Tuple>
auto helper(std::index_sequence<Is...> Seq, const Tuple& t)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(helper1<Is>(Seq, t)...);
}

template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
void apply_to_neighboor(F&& f, Ts... indexes)
{
    std::apply(std::forward<F>(f),
               helper(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>(), std::tie(indexes...)));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcc30a49d4ef9f03)

Comment: Very clever way of picking each dimension in turn!

Comment: That's very interesting but this does not really answer OP's question which is to have single call to a function `func` which takes an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: @Holt: I hope added version fills the gap you noticed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible implementation that rely on your `MArr` providing a custom subscript operator:

```
// Subscript using an array of size_t
T operator[](const size_t (&idx)[sizeof... (sizes) + 1]) const;
```

The idea is as follows:

1. You generate a sequence from `0` to `2 * D * D - 1` (where `D` is the number of dimensions).
2. Using this sequence, you generate all the indices in a single 1D array `x + 1`, `y`, `z`, `x - 1`, `y`, `z`, ..., `x`, `y`, `z + 1`, `x`, `y`, `z - 1`.
3. You treat this huge array as an array of `2 * D` arrays of `D` values (`size_t [2 * D][D]`).
4. You use this array to index your multi-dimensional array using the newly defined subscript operator.

And here would be the implementation:

```
template <class T, std::size_t... Sizes, class F, class... Is,
          std::size_t... IsP2N, std::size_t... IsP2NN>
auto around_impl(MArr<T, Sizes...> const& arr,
                 std::index_sequence<IsP2N...>,
                 std::index_sequence<IsP2NN...>,
                 F &&f, Is&&... pt) {
    const std::size_t pts[] = {(std::size_t)pt... };
    const std::size_t pts2[2 * sizeof...(Sizes)][sizeof...(Sizes)] = {
        (pts[IsP2NN % sizeof...(Sizes)] 
         + (1 - 2 * ((IsP2NN / sizeof...(Sizes)) % 2)) 
            * (IsP2NN % sizeof...(Sizes) == IsP2NN / (2 * sizeof...(Sizes))))...

    };
    return f(arr[pts2[IsP2N]]... );
}

template <class T, std::size_t... Sizes, class F, class... Is>
auto around(MArr<T, Sizes...> const& arr, F &&f, Is&&... pt) {
    return around_impl(arr,
                       std::make_index_sequence<2 * sizeof...(Sizes)>{},
                       std::make_index_sequence<2 * sizeof...(Sizes) * sizeof...(Sizes)>{},
                       std::forward<F>(f),
                       std::forward<Is>(pt)... );
}
```

Small notes on the implementation:

- The computation that takes place inside the brackets is explained at the end of this answer.
- The initialization of a 2D array from a single brace-enclosed list is valid C++ (as far as I know).
- Most of this is optimized out by clang with `-O3`.

You can then call:

```
// 3D array
MArr<int, 4, 4, 4> arr;

// Function to call:
auto myFun = [](int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) { 
    return a + b + c + d + e + f;
};

// Call around:
around(arr, myFun, x, y, z);
```

To call:

```
myFun(arr[x + 1, y, z], arr[x - 1, y, z], 
      arr[x, y + 1, z], arr[x, y - 1, z],
      arr[x, y, z + 1], arr[x, y, z - 1]);
```

---

Explanation of:

```
(pts[IsP2NN % sizeof...(Sizes)] 
 + (1 - 2 * ((IsP2NN / sizeof...(Sizes)) % 2)) 
    * (IsP2NN % sizeof...(Sizes) == IsP2NN / (2 * sizeof...(Sizes))))...
```

- `IsP2NN` goes from `0` to `2 * D * D - 1`.
- `pts[...]` corresponds to `x`, `y`, `z`, `x`, `y`, `z`, ..., and so on.
- `1 - ...` parts generates `1`, `1`, `1`, `-1`, `-1`, `-1`, `1`, `1`, `1`, `-1`, `-1`, `-1`, and so on... It alternates between sequences of `1` and `-1`.
- `* (...)` will nullify the previous sequence when the dimension does not match, it generates `1`, `0`, `0`, `1`, `0`, `0`, `0`, `1`, `0`, `0`, `1`, `0`, and so on...

Here is a "matrix" view of what happens:

```
Is          0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17

Is % 3      0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
Is / 3 % 2  0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1
Is / 6      0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2

pts  --     x   y   z   x   y   z   x   y   z   x   y   z   x   y   z   x   y   z
     --     1   0   0  -1   0   0   0   1   0   0  -1   0   0   0   1   0   0  -1
     --     1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          x+1   y   z x-1   y   z   x y+1   z   x y-1   z   x   y z+1   x   y z-1
```

Comment: Thanks for your very clear reply. Could you give me a quick pointer how you would implement the array subscript? I feel like this won't be possible recursively because I can only access one "layer" of my array at a time?

Comment: @Faser You cannot implement this one directly recursively, but you can fall back to a protected operator that would take a `size_t*` that would be trivial to implement recursively (just increment the pointer before calling the next function).

Comment: @Faser Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Holt59/24c09c94245b1a25966122474d44c321), but a custom aggregate type for subscripting would probably be better.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd create an index type.

```
template<std::size_t N>
using index=std::array<std::size_t, N>;

template<class T, size_t size, size_t... sizes>
struct MArr {
  using my_index=index<sizeof...(sizes)+1>;
```

and an index ref.  Either use `gsl::span` or write your own:

```
namespace utility {
  template<class It>
  struct range {
    It b,e;
    It begin()const{return b;}
    It end()const{return e;}
    std::size_t size()const{return std::distance(begin(),end());}
    bool empty()const{return begin()==end();}

    using reference=typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference;

    reference front()const{return *begin();}
    reference back()const{return *std::prev(end());}
  };
  template<class T>
  struct span:range<T*> {
    span(T* s, T*f):range<T*>{s,f}{}
    span():span(nullptr,nullptr){}
    span(T*s,std::size_t len):span(s,s+len){}
    T&operator[](std::size_t i)const{return this->begin()[i];}
    T* data()const{return this->begin();}
    span without_front(std::size_t n=1)const{ return {this->begin()+(std::min)(n,this->size()), end()}; }
    span without_back(std::size_t n=1)const{ return {this->begin(), end()-(std::min)(n,this->size())}; }
    span only_front(std::size_t n=1)const{ return {this->begin(),this->begin()+(std::min)(n,this->size())}; }
    span only_back(std::size_t n=1)const{ return {end()-(std::min)(n,this->size()),end()}; }
    span mid(std::size_t start, std::size_t len)const{ return without_front(start).only_front(len); }

    template< class U >
    using compatible=std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_convertible<U*,T*>{}&&(sizeof(U)==sizeof(T))>;
    template<class R>
    using compatible_range=compatible< std::decay_t<decltype( *std::declval<R>().data() )> >;
    template<class C,
      std::enable_if_t< compatible_range< C& >, bool> =true, // has .data() that returns good type
      std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same<span, std::decay_t<C>>{}, bool> =true // not own type
    >
    span(C&& c): span( c.data(), c.size() ){}
    template<std::size_t N>
    span( T(&arr)[N] ):span(arr, N){}
    // etc
  };
}
```

once you have span (either like above, or from gsl), the code becomes much cleaner:

```
template<std::size_t N>
using index=std::array<std::size_t, N>;

using index_cref=utility::span<std::size_t const>;
using index_ref=utility::span<std::size_t>;

template<class T, size_t size, size_t... sizes>
struct MArr {
  using my_index=index<sizeof...(sizes)+1>;
  T& operator[]( index_cref r ){ return data[r.front()][ r.without_front() ]; }
```

and in the one-dim case

```
T& operator[](index_cref r) {
   return data[r.front()];
}
```

once we have done this your problem becomes easier.

First we rewrite your `func` to iterate over values of an `index`.  This can be done the way you did it, where you pass in a callback, or you could implement `next` which advances an index.

```
bool next_index( index_ref r, index_cref bounds ){
  if (r.empty()||bounds.empty()) return false;
  ++r.back();
  if (r.back()!=bounds.back()) return true;
  r.back()=0;
  return next_index( r.without_back(), bounds.without_back() );
}
```

now iterating can look like this:

```
template<class MArr, class F>
void foreach_index( MArr const&, F&& f ){
  using index=typename MArr::index;
  index const bounds = MArr::bounds(); // todo: write
  index cur = {{0}};
  do {
    f(cur);
  } while( next_index(cur, bounds) );
}
```

which is cleaner, simpler and more efficient than your version (no type erasure).

Nearest neighbour can be written in terms of `index_ref` easily.

```
template<class F>
void foreach_neighbour( index_ref where, index_cref bounds, F&& f ){
  for(std::size_t i=0; i<(std::min)(where.size(),bounds.size());++i){
    if (where[i]){ where[i]--; f(where); where[i]++; }
    if (where[i]+1<bounds[i]) { where[i]++; f(where); where[i]--; }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no clue what all this does. I can see no evidence of the claim of "cleaner, simpler". The claim "more efficient" due to replacing `std::function` with a template makes sense, but does not require this template beast you wrote.

Comment: What purpose does writing `(std::min)(n,this->size())` instead of `std::min(n,this->size())` serve?

Comment: @nwp: I bet three leek slices on "so that the stupid `min` macro from MSVC doesn't kick in".

Comment: @nwp It is much faster because it does not use recursion extensively, not because `std::function` was replaced with a template.

Comment: @nwp the end "user" code is simpler; span is "library" or "vocabulary" code.  If you have span you'll find (in my experience) you'll use it everywhere.