# Implementing subscript operator that accepts an array of indices

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, variadic-templates, c++17

This is a continuation of my question [Implement STL functions in variadic template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959900/implement-stl-functions-in-variadic-template/47960924#47960924):

How can I implement a subscript operator for an `N`-dimensional array that accepts an array of length `N`, given that a already have defined "single-layer" subscript operators to be used as `array[indx0][indx1]…[indxN]`. I feel like there should be a simple fold expression for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `[]` is not one of the foldable operators. Bummer. But we just have to cheat a bit and piggyback on another one :)

```
namespace indexer_detail {
    template <class T>
    struct ArrayWrapper {
        T obj;
    };

    template <class T>
    ArrayWrapper(T&&) -> ArrayWrapper<T&&>;

    template <class T>
    auto operator & (ArrayWrapper<T> const &aw, std::size_t N) {
        return ArrayWrapper{aw.obj[N]};
    }
}

template <std::size_t Size, class Array, std::size_t... Idx>
decltype(auto) index(
    Array &&array,
    std::array<std::size_t, Size> const &indices,
    std::index_sequence<Idx...>
) {
    return (
        indexer_detail::ArrayWrapper{std::forward<Array>(array)} & ... & indices[Idx]
    ).obj;
}

template <std::size_t Size, class Array>
decltype(auto) index(Array &&array, std::array<std::size_t, Size> const &indices) {
    return index(std::forward<Array>(array), indices, std::make_index_sequence<Size>{});
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa16b4b2fb1d4fd0)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's C++17, we can use constexpr if to make more it simple :

```
template<size_t Idx0, size_t... IdxRest, typename V>
decltype(auto) getval(const V& v)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(IdxRest) == 0)
    {
        return v[Idx0];
    }
    else
    {
        return getval<IdxRest...>(v[Idx0]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10][10] = { 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<int> arr2 = { 1,2,3 };
    auto v1 = getval<0, 2>(arr);
    auto v2 = getval<1>(arr2);
    return 0;
}
```